How to ignore a route in the Next.js build step?
I am using Next.js 14, with the app router.
I have a /prototypes route that I want to see in dev mode, but I don't want to transpile it to the production build.
I've tried to use ignore-loader as suggested here, but the build crashes.
next.config.mjs
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  webpack: (config) => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /app\/prototypes\/.*/,
        loader: 'ignore-loader',
      });
    }
    return config
  }
}

export default nextConfig


I have excluded the folder in tsconfig.json too:
{
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "app/prototypes/**/*.tsx"]
}

error message:
Error occurred prerendering page "/prototypes". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

Error: Unsupported Server Component type: {...}

The build step works well without that webpack config, so I suspect the problem is related to it.
In the meantime i'm doing this to not show the prototypes to our users in prod (although this would include them in the bundle I think?).
Adding this for the benefit of people with a similar use case to mine.
app/prototypes/page.tsx
import { notFound } from "next/navigation"

export default function PrototypePage() {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    notFound()
  }
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Prototypes</h1>
      <p>Here go the component prototypes</p>
    </>
  )
}

